# woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook not working in cart widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, cart

I’m hooking an action to woocommerce_before_calculate_totals

The item prices are updated on the cart page successfully. But the prices in the cart widget stay at 0? Only thing that is changed in the cart widget is the subtotal.

Here is my function

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_total_price', 99  );

function add_custom_total_price( $cart_object ) {
session_start();
global $woocommerce;

foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

    if ($value['variation']['price-type'] == 'abonne') {
        $value['data']->price = 6;
        $value['data']->sale_price = 6;
        $value['data']->regular_price = 6;
    }else if ($value['variation']['price-type'] == 'jeune') {
        $value['data']->price = 4;
        $value['data']->sale_price = 4;
        $value['data']->regular_price = 4;
    }

    $value['line_total'] = intval($value['quantity'] * $value['data']->price);

    unset($value['variation']['price-type']);
}
```

}

The checkout is working well and order is generated correctly...
What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.